# Are the following inlined functions guaranteed to have the same implementation?

Tags: c++, inline-functions

- Are the following functions guaranteed to have the same implementation (i.e. object code)?
- Does this change if `Foo` below is a primitive type instead (e.g. `int`)?
- Does this change with the size of `Foo`?

Returning by value:

```
inline Foo getMyFooValue() { return myFoo; }

Foo foo = getMyFooValue();
```

Returning by reference:

```
inline const Foo &getMyFooReference() { return myFoo; }

Foo foo = getMyFooReference();
```

Modifying in place:

```
inline void getMyFooInPlace(Foo &theirFoo) { theirFoo = myFoo; }

Foo foo;
getMyFooInPlace(foo);
```

Comment: The emitted code for the functions themselves (e.g., if their addresses are taken) is obviously different. Do you mean if the code at the call site, after inlining, will change? Also, one of those is not like the others.

Comment: And if you ask about guarantees, there are none anyway. The compiler can do what it wants (e.g. perform inlining or not!) as long as the observable behaviour is the same. For example, it could simply emit assembler which uses direct values instead of referencing true memory if myFoo can be proven to not change.

Comment: In addition to my formal response below I understand that you assume that returning a const reference to a primitive type would possibly be implemented as returning a copy of the value. While the compiler may do that with high optimizations and inlining in cases where only the value is required I would think that if somebody takes the address (somewhere else!) of what `getMyFooReference()` returns the compiler may always emit true "references" even when the value is asked for (i.e. addresses which need dereferencing), at least with low optimizations.

Comment: I didn't consider getting the address of the reference! Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the following functions guaranteed to have the same implementation (i.e. object code)?

No, the language only specifies behaviour, not code generation, so it's up to the compiler whether two pieces of code with equivalent behaviour produce the same object code.

> Does this change if `Foo` below is a primitive type instead (e.g. `int`)?

If it is (or, more generally, if it's *trivially copyable*), then all three have the same behaviour, so can be expected to produce similar code.

If it's a non-trivial class type, then it depends on what the class's special functions do. Each calls these functions in slightly different ways:

- The first might copy-initialise a temporary object (calling the copy constructor), copy-initialise `foo` with that, then destroy the temporary (calling the destructor); but more likely it will elide the temporary, becoming equivalent to the second.
- The second will copy-initialise `foo` (calling the copy constructor)
- The third will default initialise `foo` (calling the default constructor), then copy-assign to it (calling the assignment operator).

So whether or not they are equivalent depends on whether default-initialisation and copy-assignment has equivalent behaviour to copy-initialisation, and (perhaps) whether creating and destroying a temporary has side effects. If they are equivalent, then you'll probably get similar code.

> Does this change with the size of `Foo`?

No the size is irrelevant. What matters is whether it's trivial (so that both copy initialisation and copy assignment simply copy bytes) or non-trivial (so that they call user-defined functions, which might or might not be equivalent to each other).

Comment: With -O0 I'd expect differences, possibly not even inlining. Also, if anybody gets the idea to take the address of the const ref (in code which is not shown here, but ovbviously it's only a snippet, right?) I'd expect the code of getMyFooReference() to return a reference, i.e. address in assembler.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Good point. I interpreted the question as "do these function *calls* have the same implementation"; but it's worth noting that the functions themselves (if not inlined, or used in ways that expose their difference) won't, since they can have different behaviour.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, `the language only specifies behaviour, not code generation`. I agree that obviously the language doesn't determine the code that would be generated, but it can put some constraints on the executable other than the behaviour alone, for instance RVOs and move semantics. Personally, I had the same question as the questioner. This sort of vagueness in the language seems terrible and unnecessary. If I have a small and oft-used function that I want to provide to others in library code, I'd like to be truly certain that any compiler is going to inline the function in a sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

The standard draft N3337 contains the following rules in 1.9.5: "A conforming [C++] implementation [...] shall produce the same observable behaviour as one of the possible executions of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with the same program and the same input." And in 1.9.9 it defines the observable behaviour basically as I/O and volatile's values. Which means that as long as the I/O and volatiles of your program stay the same the implementation can do what it wants. If you have no I/O or volatiles the program doesn't need to do anything (which makes benchmarks hard to get right with high optimizations).

Note that the standard specifically is totally silent about what code a compiler should emit. Hell, it could probably *interpret* the sources.

This answers your question: No.